# How do you make WakeLock pop app to foreground

Tags: android, android-wake-lock

I want my app to run in the background or after the phone has been put to sleep and when you near a certain latitude and longitude my app will immediately pop to the foreground.  this must work no matter if it was from sleep or another app was in foreground.
I am using a service and a WakeLock.  I am pretty sure the service is working but I don't know how to check because the debugger returns nothing if it is not in the foregrond.  If it is working then my WakeLock is not working as anticipated.

```
public abstract class WakeLocker {

private static PowerManager.WakeLock fullWakeLock;
private static PowerManager.WakeLock partialWakeLock;
private static PowerManager pm;

public static void acquire(Context context) {
    if (fullWakeLock != null) fullWakeLock.release();
    if (partialWakeLock != null) partialWakeLock.release();

    pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    fullWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock((PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK |
            PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK |
            PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP), "Loneworker - FULL WAKE LOCK");
    partialWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "Loneworker - PARTIAL WAKE LOCK");
    partialWakeLock.acquire();
}

public static void release() {
    if (fullWakeLock != null) {
        fullWakeLock.release();
        fullWakeLock = null;
    }
    if (partialWakeLock != null) {
        partialWakeLock.release();
        partialWakeLock = null;
    }
}

public static void wakeDevice(Context context) {
        fullWakeLock.acquire();

        //KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) context.getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
        //KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock keyguardLock = keyguardManager.newKeyguardLock("TAG");
        //keyguardLock.disableKeyguard();

}

public static boolean fullWakeLockActive() {
   return fullWakeLock != null;
}
```

}

the fullWakeLock is being acquired here

```
if (makeUseOfNewLocation(location) < 20) {
                if (WakeLocker.fullWakeLockActive())
                    WakeLocker.wakeDevice(allert.getMA());
                if (callProgress.isOffHook()) {
                    new BlinkBack(allert.getMA());
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

The wake lock itself cannot wake the device from sleep or cause your so to come to the foreground. You would have to use location services or an alarm to wake the device up, then use your wake lock to keep the device awake and trigger a UI component of your app to the foreground.

Comment: so following your advice I have found.  public void addProximityAlert (double latitude, double longitude, float radius, long expiration, PendingIntent intent).  I am assuming that I use that intent, but how do I bring to foreground or wake the phone with this?

Comment: It's not clear from the docs, but adding a proximity alert should cause the system to periodically wake up to check location and if you have entered the area then it will notify you.  You'll want to use a `PendingIntent` for a `BroadcastReceiver`.  Your receiver can then activate your UI, post a notification, etc. by firing its own `Intent`.  You'll most likely need to manage your own `Wakelock` when doing this, though.  Have a look at the `WakefulReceiver` as an easier way to handle the lock in your app.

Comment: ok i looked into addproximityalert and I decided that it is probably not the way to go since I have already logic build to fire a whole bunch of stuff.  would this work.
if (makeUseOfNewLocation(location) < 20) {
                    allert.getContext().sendBroadcast(new Intent(allert.getContext(), MainActivity.class));
                    if (WakeLocker.fullWakeLockActive())
                        WakeLocker.wakeDevice(allert.getMA());

if so I assume I put the receiver in my background service?

Comment: It's difficult to say if the code would work or not without a more detailed picture.  This is using a number of app-specific APIs so I can't really tell you if it'll do what you want.  Note that a `BroadcastReceiver` is a component which is not necessarily tied to a `Service` or an `Activity`.  It is a separate component which has its own lifecycle.

Comment: hmm i am quite lost.  if you have the time, what more amount of picture would you need?  currently I have created the receiver to only run when I activate a background service.  I am at a loss on this topic

Comment: I don't have a location based example I can point you at, but I do have an alarm based one which covers similar concepts: wake the device and cause a UI to come to the foreground.  Note that this could be very undesirable for end users.  But, it'll help demonstrate the concepts for you (including use of a wakelock). This is an article I wrote to explain the Android `AlarmManager` and its use: http://po.st/7UpipA

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74672/discussion-between-chad-and-larry-schiefer).